# Guitar effects explanation books

Tags: audio, reference-request, music

Can you please suggest some books to get how guitar effects: distortion, overdrive, phaser and so on are achieved ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[DAFX](http://books.google.com/books/about/DAFX.html?id=h90HIV0uwVsC) is a pretty good one.

[Harmony Central](http://www.harmonycentral.com) used to have a surprisingly good knowledgeable base for algorithms but that seem to have disappeared since Guitar Center took them over.

A lot of source code can be found at http://www.musicdsp.org/, but it's fairly varied in quality.

Comment: The second edition of the DAFX book is now available

http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470665998.html


It is nice as it is entirely focussed on audio effects processing.

Comment: @learnvst DAFX is *amazing*!!!

Comment: Thanks, I believe it's a great book, but can you recommend another simpler book if possible

Answer (score 3):

If you want something a bit more simple than the Dafx book then I recommend this dissertation that i stumbled across a while back. Even if you have no idea how to use simulink, the diagrams might help you understand how the various guitar effects are realized.

http://cegt201.bradley.edu/projects/proj2008/gegudps/Czubak_Raheja_Final_Paper.pdf

Comment: Come to think of it, shouldn't these types of post be in the community wiki?

Comment: I also found this book http://www.amazon.com/Audio-Programming-Book-Richard-Boulanger/dp/0262014467/ref=reg_hu-rd_dp_img